# Retrieve all ids where `name` LIKE %current_name in one query

Tags: mysql

I have a table like:

```
id | name
1  | gecko
2  | b-gecko
3  | c-gecko
4  | toucan
5  | s-toucan
```

I would like to retrieve in a single query `id`,`name` and `lookalike` fields. Something like:

```
id | name   | lookalike
1  | gecko  | 1,2,3
4  | toucan | 4,5
```

... or like:

```
id | name   | lookalike
1  | gecko  | 2
1  | gecko  | 3
4  | toucan | 5
```

Is this even possible? I have like 50,000 records in that table and it would require a lot of simple queries for each record if checking row by row.

I think the query should look something like:

```
SELECT t1.`id`, t1.`name`, (SELECT t2.`id` FROM `table1` t2 WHERE t2.`name` LIKE CONCAT('%', t1.`name`)) as `lookalike` FROM `table1` t1
```

... but I'm missing a concat. Thank you!

**LE:** Even if using

```
SELECT t1.`id`, t1.`name`, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ',') FROM `table1` t2 WHERE t2.`name` LIKE CONCAT('%', t1.`name`) AND t1.name<>t2.name) as `lookalike` FROM `table1` t1
```

I get a lot of server crashes due to the large amount of rows to be checked. I know that I have the worst situation for the LIKE, but I'm trying to figure out how to optimize this.

For the 2nd version I've tried

```
SELECT 
    t.id,
    t.name,
    t2.id
FROM 
    table1 t 
LEFT JOIN 
    table1 t2 
ON 
    t2.name LIKE CONCAT('%', t.name)
```

but this one crashes the server too.

Comment: from where the field `lookalike` comes?

Comment: It is generated by a subquery that searches for the ids of the rows having the `name` ending the same as the initial row ... pardon my lack of clearly explaining, but please see what is the desired result

Comment: And what is the result of your query?

Comment: The query returns all the rows but in the `lookalike` field I get same value as in `id`. Now the beast crashes the server when trying to sort results by `lookalike`.

Answer (score 1):

Mysql has a GROUP_CONCAT function, which allows you to convert the subquery to a string.

Also, there's no use in including the row itself as a lookalike, so you should filter out the original animal in the subquery

Here's an example of how you can do this.

```
SELECT *,
   (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ', ')
   FROM table1
   WHERE `name` LIKE '%toucan%'
   AND `name` != 'toucan') as lookalikes
FROM table1
WHERE `name` = 'toucan'
```

The result here would be

```
id | name    | lookalikes
4  | toucan  | 5
```

Comment: The server keeps crashing if using this method, there are 2.5 billions rows that are checked :( ... is there a way to ignore rows in the result if `lookalikes` IS NULL or equals ''?

Comment: You could look into optimizing your queries with indexes. I don't know if you're familiar with this? 

You can do this by using the EXPLAIN statement. Here's some reading material: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html

Comment: In addition to this, I don't really see the point of retrieving the data the way you do. I suppose you're going to query the database again to get the data for the lookalikes. 

You could just retrieve the ids of the lookalikes, instead of adding the name and id field of the original row. In that case, you're query can be simplified to `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM test WHERE name LIKE '%toucan%'`

Comment: I know how to use indexes, but they don't help here. Basically I want to get all the look-alike names in that table just in one query and, from what I've noticed, there are some duplicates with odd prefixes. Even the EXPLAIN statement crashes the server with 500 error.